# Get MySQL LOAD DATA Command Logs Using Bash Script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to use bash script to get the **records loaded** in the MySQL. How can we get this information using script?

```
mysql> load data infile "directory path/test.txt" into table DEMO;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (1.35 sec)
Records: 4 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Comment: `mysql -e "LOAD DATA ..."` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: What do you mean by `to get the records loaded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data using bash script you can simply use `mysql -e` flag in the script as suggested by @Akina in the comment.

If by

> records loaded

you mean you wish to get the records affected by load statement then you can use verbose flag (`mysql -v -e`) in your bash script.

> --verbose, -v Verbose mode. Produce more output about what the program does. This option can be given multiple times to produce more and more output. (For example, -v -v -v produces table
> output format even in batch mode.)

Below is an **example script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="mysql_user"
PASSWORD="your_password"

load_stats=`mysql -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} -D your_db -v -v -e "load data infile '/tmp/test.txt' into table DEMO"`
echo "${load_stats}"
```

**Output:**

```
--------------
load data infile '/tmp/test.txt' into table DEMO
--------------

Query OK, 3 rows affected
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Bye
```